# Is `while(*p++ = *(p+1));` undefined behavior?

Tags: c, while-loop, undefined-behavior, post-increment

I have code that manipulate C-string with one-line `while` loop statement.
It works perfectly when compiled with MSVC2015, but gives different outcome when compiled with TDM-GCC (gcc (tdm-1) 5.1.0).

Here is a minimal example that shows the problem. The code overwrites current char with next char, repeat over and over again until it sets the current char to `\0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[999] = "Foobar", *p = buf;
    while(*p++ = *(p+1));
    printf("buf = %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

When the code is compiled with MSVC2015, the output is `buf = oobar` as expected. With TDM-GCC, however, the output is `buf = obar`.

If I change the while statement to `while(*p = *(p+1)) { ++p; }`, both compiler will give the expected result `buf = oobar`. It seems that by putting the post-increment operator inside the expression, I have triggered undefined behavior somehow.

My question is, **why the code behaves differently when compiled with different compiler**? Is it wrong (or non-standard) to put increment operator inside a non-trivial `while` statement? Did I trigger undefined behavior? If so, how should the code behave according to the C standard? If not, who is to blame here? TDM-GCC? MSVC?

UPDATE: For those in future who have the same doubt as me, the answer is: **Yes, the code invokes UB.** The well-defined way is to do like this: `while(*p = *(p+1)){++p;}`

---

Someone asked why would we want to code like this. Here is a scenario where this idiom can be useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

static void EscapeDquote(char * const sz)
{
    char *p = sz;
    BOOL bs = FALSE;
    for (; *p; ++p)
    {
        if (*p == '\\') {
            bs = !bs;
            continue;
        }
        if (*p == '\"') {
            if (bs) {
                /*
                    discard prev char (backslash before dquote)
                    overwrite with next char until null-termi
                */
                char *q = --p;
                /* OLD version, not OK for GCC */
                /* while(*q++ = *(q+1)); */
                /* Safer version, works in GCC as well: */
                while(*q = *(q+1)){++q;}
            }
        }
        bs = FALSE;
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* "call \"D:\foo bar.exe\" */
    char szTest[] = "call \\\"D:\\foo bar.exe\\\"";
    printf("Before = %s\n", szTest);
    EscapeDquote(szTest);
    printf("After  = %s\n", szTest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why writing code that way in the first place?

Comment: probably missing a sequence point somewhere, but hurts my head trying to know why. When you code stuff like this, there's already undefined behaviour in your head. If you want speed why not trying assembly? at least it's deterministic

Comment: @rsp `p` is only modified once in the expression

Comment: The actual definition of "post", as in post-increment, is apparently left somewhat in the air. Some compilers apply it after the statement has been parsed and others after the left hand side. To be on the safe side, put p++ inside the while block so that you can guarantee what you're going to get.

Comment: @Jean Short code, and it does the job. Let's say I want to modify a string buffer so all double quotes would be removed. With this idiom I can overwrite the dquote with next char, over and over again until the end.

Comment: And I don't think I modify the `p` twice as @M.M said. It is `(p+1)` not `(++p)`.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, I think it's safer that way. BTW it seems SO really hate people write such code. I thought it's commonplace to do thing this way when you do low-level programming.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: I cannot see why this question gets downvoted. It's clear and interesting.

Comment: 'and it does the job' - aparrently not, since you are asking aboout it here. 'SO really hate people write such code. I thought it's commonplace to do thing this way when you do low-level programming' - not if you want to be able to easily debug it, it's not.  'Clever' code is bad code.

Comment: @MartinJames That's why I want to confirm the correctness of such code, because I would be in big trouble if the code goes wrong due to UB. Code like `while(*p++ = *q++);` are very obscure, but at the same time they are so short and make your code clean, provided you're fully sure what it does.

Comment: 'provided you're fully sure what it does' - exactly.  You re not sure, so you ask here.  That makes is bad code, not clean code.  Imagine what some maintenance/enhancement developer thinks when hunting some obscure bug, and finds code like yours?  Such thoughts cannot be published on a public site:)

Comment: @MartinJames Are you suggesting that if I have doubt on such code, I shall not ask it on SO? Seriously? I knew my code could be UB, that's why I asked, "Is this UB?", yet you're saying as if I'm promoting bad code by asking it here.

Comment: @raymai97 By all means ask on SO, and you have.  My comment on it is that your code is bad, whether correct or not.  Also, I'm not suggesting that you are promoting bad code, merely publishing it here.  If the result is that, in the future, fewer developers write code that is difficult-to-debug, and possibly incorrect, then I call that a win overall.

Comment: If you know the string length (you do know in the example scenario), use `memmove()`: `memmove(szTest, szTest+1, sizeof szTest - 1); `

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question, it makes it confusing for future readers. The format of the site is that you accept the answer that best answers the question

Comment: @klutt once you've read a few thousand questions about stacking increment operators with other increment/assignment operators, it is much less interesting...  "don't do that, even if you think you have it figured out, other people reading the code will be confused" applies to all such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is undefined behaviour, because [Clang](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang) compiler gives following error:

```
source_file.cpp:6:13: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'p' [-Wunsequenced]
    while(*p++ = *(p+1));
            ^      ~
```

**C11: 6.5 Expressions:**

> If a side effect on a scalar **object is unsequenced** relative to either
>   a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
>   computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   **undefined**. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
>   subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an
>   unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings

Comment: I think I need a better compiler. My TDM-GCC just wouldn't tell me this even with `-Wall`. Thanks for showing me this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-Wall` If you are using GCC compiler. It is indeed an undefined behaviour in both C & C++.

See live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/973d29bd2498b9dd).

See the diagnosis given by compiler

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:6:13: warning: operation on 'p' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

     while(*p++ = *(p+1));

            ~^~
```

Comment: My TDM-GCC would only show `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]` with the same command-line. What version of gcc do you use?

Answer (score 3):

It is undefined behaviour, because the following two operations are unsequenced:

- The write to `p` in `p++`
- The read of `p` in `(p+1)`

Comment: Thanks, so if I put the increment operator inside the while block, the code behavior will be well-defined, right?

Comment: @raymai97 if what you mean is `while( p[0] = p[1] ) { ++p; }` yes that would be well-defined (and infinitely more readable).  I'm not sure whether you intended to increment `p` in the case that `p[0] == 0` though; if so then you'd need to write something different

Answer (score 1):

It is *undefined behavior* as there is sequence point not defined.

Workaround would be `while ((*p = *(p + 1)) && p++);` if you want it in single line.

Now you will first set your pointer and if assigned value is *non-zero*, you will continue with defined sequence to `p++` statement. If assignment value is *zero*, while loop will end means string was shifted.

Comment: If I do it this way, the behavior will be well-defined, right?

Comment: @raymai97 This is defined way in C